# Trying to delete elements from a database SQLite3 from a tkinter treeview GUI using python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite, treeview

I have been working on project for my class dealing with GUI in python. I am using tkinter. I have a treeview and I am displaying data in the treeview from a database from SQlite DB. However, I added a delete function to be able to select values from the treeview and then delete them with the delete function and button, I keep getting the same issue: The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied. I have a tuple though so I am quite confused as to why I am getting this error. 
Please help.!

```
def delete():
    conn2 = sq.connect('Clients.db')
    c2 = conn2.cursor()
    for selected_item in tree1.selection():
        c2.execute("DELETE FROM clients WHERE name=? AND phone=?",           (tree1.set(selected_item, '#1'), ))
    conn2.commit()
    tree1.delete(selected_item)
```

I keep getting get this when I select a value from the treeview and hit the delete button. ( By the way, the delete button is binded with the delete function): sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.

I want to be able to select a value from the treeview and then hit delete and it will delete. Please help. Thank you

Comment: `(tree1.set(selected_item, '#1'), )` is a tuple with a single element (Whatever `tree1.set(...)` returns). Your query needs two elements to bind to the parameters in it.

Comment: so tree1.set(selected_item,'#1') is one element? How would I add another? I added the ( tree1....), ) comma to make it two. So I still get errors.

Comment: `(a,)` is a one element tuple. The trailing comma makes it a tuple and not just a single value. You'd need something like `(a, b)` for a two element tuple. If whatever that method returns is a two-element tuple with the values you want, then just use that - otherwise if you make it part of a tuple, you'd have a tuple where one of the elements is itself a tuple.

Comment: How would that be illustrated?